# How do you set a Pandas function condition to be one record equal to itself offset by X recods?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm defining a simple if xxxx return y - else return `NaN` function. If the record, `['Product']`, equals `['Product']` offset by 8 then the `if` condition is true. Here's an example of what the initial dataframe looks like.

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   Product  Sales Quarter
0  Shoes    25    12017
1  Shoes    3     22017
2  Shoes    6     32017
3  Shoes    23    42017
4  Shoes    11    12018
5  Shoes    12    22018
6  Shoes    9     32018
7  Shoes    45    42018
8  Shoes    3     12019
9  Jacket   12    12017
10 Jacket   10    22017
...
16 Jacket   23    42018
17 Jacket   44    12019
```

I've tried calling the record and setting it equal to itself offset by `8` using `==` and `.shift(8)`. `['Product']` is a string and `['Sales']` is an integer.

```py
def Growth (X):
    if X['Product'] == X['Product'].shift(8):
        return (1+ X['Sales'].shift(4)) / (1+ X['Sales'].shift(8) - 1)
    else:
        return 'NaN'
```

I expect the output to be NaN for the first 8 records, and then to have numbers at record 9 (like shown below), but I receive the error instead.

```py
   Product  Sales Quarter Growth
0  Shoes    25    12017   NaN
1  Shoes    3     22017   NaN
2  Shoes    6     32017   NaN
3  Shoes    23    42017   NaN
4  Shoes    11    12018   NaN
5  Shoes    12    22018   NaN
6  Shoes    9     32018   NaN
7  Shoes    45    42018   NaN
8  Shoes    3     12019  -.54
9  Jacket   12    12017   NaN
10 Jacket   10    12017   NaN
...
16 Jacket   23    42018   NaN
17 Jacket   44    12019   ##
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) because you just have to set a different value of `NaN`:

```
df['Growth'] = ( (1+ df['Sales'].shift(4)) / (1+ df['Sales'].shift(8) - 1) ).where(df['Product'] == df['Product'].shift(8))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Product  Sales  Quarter  Growth
0    Shoes     25    12017     NaN
1    Shoes      3    22017     NaN
2    Shoes      6    32017     NaN
3    Shoes     23    42017     NaN
4    Shoes     11    12018     NaN
5    Shoes     12    22018     NaN
6    Shoes      9    32018     NaN
7    Shoes     45    42018     NaN
8    Shoes      3    12019    0.48
9   Jacket     12    12017     NaN
10  Jacket     10    22017     NaN
```

---

Alsoy you can use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Growth'] = ( (1+ df['Sales'].shift(4)) / (1+ df['Sales'].shift(8) - 1) ).mask(df['Product'] != df['Product'].shift(8))
```